# Calling Powershell Pretty Console Output from c#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Powershell has some pretty nifty formating modules for displaying objects, arrays, collections, dictionaries, and tabular data.

Since Powershell is all .NET, I'm assuming there is a Assembly containing the logic for this.

**Who can come up with a way to call these powershell formating from .NET:**

I'd imagine something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Powershell.DisplayObject(obj))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how you do it in V2:

```
PowerShell.Create().AddScript("get-Process |Out-String").Invoke()
```

The key thing is to call OUT-STRING.

Experiment! Enjoy! Engage!

Jeffrey Snover [MSFT]
Windows Management Partner Architect

Comment: what do you know about powershell anyway? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to control the width of the output with | out-string -width 120 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be where you are going here but check out the Extended Type System.

Here's a good spot to start:
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714419(VS.85).aspx)
[PS blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/09/06/hate-add-member-powershell-s-adaptive-type-system.aspx)
[blog](http://jtruher.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!7143DA6E51A2628D!148.entry)